# OpenCV calculate the area

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to calculate the area of what 'see' my camera. I need it to decide if the object is close or not (to control my robot). In the old version I've got this code:

```
moments = cv.Moments(mat, 0)
area = cv.GetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0)
moment10 = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0)
moment01 = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 0,1)
```

and everything was working, but now i want to do this with the nev api (cv2). This is my code:

```
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,127,255,0)

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)

area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
```

and I'm gettin the area = 0.

Or maybe instead of calculating the area the better solution is to draw a rectangle around the white area and then calculate its dimensions?

[image]

Comment: you can compute boundingRect or minEnclosingCircle of those points. Or use a closing-operator (dilate followed by erode) before contour extraction.